# Recommend me powerline wifi extension with 1 transmiter and many receiver

Tags: wifi, networking

I am thinking of buying powerline wifi extension.

I want those that have only 1 transmiter, will be located near my main modem.

I want to buy a few receivers.

So I want to avoid "pairs". The wifi would get signal from one and several

Last requirement is wifi support.

At least on the receivers one. All receivers must be able to communicate via wifi. That way I effectively have mini routers in each room.

Is this even possible?

Hard to say price range. I would say mid range. Common. Normal. I don't need super high end. Cost effective.

If there are several I want to know them all.

Let me clarify what I want

Say I want to power 10 rooms that are all far away from my main router. Does that mean I would need 20 devices? I like the one where I have 11 devices. One transmiter near my main router, and 10 receivers.

This powerline adaptor is like wifi router right? Except that their signals travel through powerline instead of through air.

If I weren't using powerline adaptor, if I use a bunch of wifi repeater, I would only need 10 devices. Can I do this with only 10 or 11 power line adapters?

$100-$200 dollar per room. I don't expect that much though. I need something cost effective. So if a $20 stuff will work, you need to give me a good reason why I should pay $150. Not exactly cheap but not spendthrift either – Jim Thio 1 min ago   edit

8 nodes should be enough. So one node near my main wifi. The other nodes should be on various rooms.

Comment: Other than missing a budget, I don't think this question is to broad and have voted to reopen. Can you provide your estimated budget?

Comment: Can't you just attach multiple powerline adapters to wifi routers? AFAIK, one-to-many doesn't require specific hardware, just regular adapter should do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple powerline adapaters  to wifi routers? Say I want to power 8 room, does that mean I would need 16 devices? I like the one where I have 9 devices. One transmiter near my main router, and 8 receivers.

Comment: This page: [TP-link info](http://www.tp-link.us/faq-434.html) may help you out a bit.

Comment: $100-$200 dollar per room. I don't expect that much though. I need something cost effective. So if a $20 stuff will work, you need to give me a good reason why I should pay $150. Not exactly cheap but not spendthrift either

Comment: 8 nodes should be enough. So one node near my main wifi. The other nodes should be on various rooms.

Comment: I see so I buy "a pair" and then when I want to add to another room I just buy another pair and I can handle 2 more rooms for every extra pair I bought. Is that how it works?

Comment: You should feasibly only need one device per room. If it is the room with your modem/router, that device will plug from the wall to the modem/router. Each other room should only need a WiFi transmitting node.